# Require.js - jQuery + jQuery dependent file (Wait untill file ready)

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have some problems with require.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min"
    },
    waitSeconds: 40
});


requirejs(['jquery', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.2/owl.carousel.min.js'], function(jQuery){
    $(function() {
        $('#carousel').owlCarousel({
            singleItem: true,
            autoPlay: true,
            stopOnHover: true,
            lazyLoad: true,
            itemsScaleUp: true
        });
    });
});
```

This only works every 2nd time i load the page (cache?)

I think i need to load my owl.carousel.js script, after jQuery is ready, but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set dependencies in the shim:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min",
        "owl" : "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.2/owl.carousel.min.js"
    },
    waitSeconds: 40,
     shim: {
            'owl': {
                //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading
                // owl
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
        }
});
```

If this doesn't work, I would recommend downloading the files for jquery and owl and placing them in your local directory because Require can be annoying with loading files from CDNs.

Comment: This error comes, when I try it use owl later "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined"

Comment: @Sam it looks like owl is still undefined for you. did you try put both owl and jquery in your local file system instead of loading from a CDN?

Comment: Yes @Evan, I've done that. and the same error occurs.

Comment: If you look at your dev tools, CMD OPTION i, and look at the network tab, are you seeing jquery and owl load in the correct order?

Answer (score -1):

You have to wrap the lib inside define function like this:

```
define(['jquery'], function( jQuery ) {
...
// OwlCarousel code
...
});
```

Some libs have implemented "AMD support" so you don't have to do this. You can check this by ctrl+f "amd" and see if the lib contains this string.